# Dragendjs stop slide on jquery-mobile slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a fullscreen mobile web page using [dragend.js](http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/).
But when I try to use a slider, dragend slides with it.
How can I disable specific elements from being dragged using dragend?

I tried:

```
$(".disable-swipe").on("touchstart mousedown", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbEgPB

But that disables the slider, too.

The slider is from jquery-mobile.

Comment: I got: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dragend is not a function`

Comment: Hackerman it seems DragendJS is not imported

Comment: Exactly....it seems that in your codepen you are importing the raw version throught https, but, the content type header for the file is plain-text; codepen is expecting a script file so the file is not loaded properly....i'm gonna do the same test in jsfiddle

Comment: Okay, I never had this problem so i didn't knew it was there.

Comment: Sven here is the proper fiddle, bug free....you can start there: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/ob6etg6y/

Comment: Now i got: `TypeError: $(...).dragend is not a function`

Comment: Hackerman everything works fine on my website but when i try to use a slider the page goes too

Video of the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKEcoEOssKE

Comment: Now i can see the behaviour...the problem is that your on-off button moves within the dragend.....

Comment: Yes, but how can i stop dragend.js from doing this?

Comment: I'm gonna implement the code in my localhost...just wait...

Comment: Okay, I tried it using `$("#page").dragend({preventDrag:true});`  but I cannot set that dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stept from dragend.js to [swiper.js](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/) because it has more functionallity

[codepen example](http://goo.gl/sxCCw4)